# How do I use my personal git config when committing as root?

Tags: git, sudo, git-config

I use [`etckeeper`](http://etckeeper.branchable.com/) for revision control of my `/etc` directory.

Due to the owership of the files under `/etc`, I need to run `git` as root.

How can I do this and still easily have access to *all* my beloved `git` aliases and other config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`git -c include.path=<file>` will include the configuration in `<file>`.

To automatically pull in my non-root user's config files, I use the `bash` alias:

```
alias gsudo='sudo git -c "include.path='"${XDG_CONFIG_DIR:-$HOME/.config}/git/config\" -c \"include.path=$HOME/.gitconfig\""
```

Then I use `gsudo` instead of `git` to both:

- Run as root
- Have access to all non-root user git configuration

Check that the config is indeed being imported:

```
gsudo config --list --show-origin --includes | less
```

Of course, you should be careful if you have any root-unsafe configuration.

Perhaps having both a "safe" and a "potentially dangerous" config file is the way to go. The user's `~/.config/git/config` could be the "potentially dangerous" one which `[include]`s the "safe" root-only config file (which is the only one used in the `gsudo` alias).